# How do I escape the git commit window from OS X terminal?

Tags: terminal, git

I am just learning git and the terminal and I wanted to make a test commit but I cannot seem to be able to escape the text editor window to save the commit[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It looks like you're inside the `vi` editor. Typing `:wq` and pressing enter should do it, i.e. save the commit message and exit.

`:` enters the command mode, `w` is for "write" (save) and `q` is for "quit".

You may need to hit escape before `:wq` to exit the insert mode (`vi` is a mode based editor).

If you want to exit without saving hit escape, `:q!` and enter.

git opens your default editor so you can edit the commit message. You can change the default editor, even to graphical text editors (such as Sublime Text). [See here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835).

Answer (score 11):

1. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (capital Z twice).

It works a bit faster.

Comment: OMG that's horrible vs code did not give any clue how to get out of it. thanks for saving my life.